# Get tf.Tensor which generated audio back from TFEvent?

Tags: python, tensorflow, wav, tensorboard

I have a `tf.Tensor` representing sound that I write to a `SummaryWriter`.

```py
from clu.metric_writers import summary_writer
import tempfile
import tensorflow as tf
import os

audio = tf.reshape(tf.linspace(0.0, 100.0, 4 * 10 * 2), (4, 10, 2))
logdir = tempfile.gettempdir()
writer = summary_writer.SummaryWriter(logdir)

writer.write_audios(step=1, audios={"o": audio}, sample_rate=2)
writer.flush()
```

Now I want to get the original `tf.Tensor` back from the Tensorboard TFEvent object. I tried this:

```py
paths = tf.io.gfile.glob(os.path.join(logdir, "events.out.tfevents.*"))
for path in paths:
    for event in tf.compat.v1.train.summary_iterator(path):
      for value in event.summary.value:
        ndarray = tf.make_ndarray(value.tensor)
        print(ndarray)
        tf.audio.decode_wav(ndarray)
```

But that gives the error:

```py
[[b'RIFFL\x00\x00\x00WAVEfmt \x10\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x10\x00data(\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f'
  b'']
 [b'RIFFL\x00\x00\x00WAVEfmt \x10\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x10\x00data(\x00\x00\x00\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f'
  b'']
 [b'RIFFL\x00\x00\x00WAVEfmt \x10\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x10\x00data(\x00\x00\x00\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f'
  b'']
 [b'RIFFL\x00\x00\x00WAVEfmt \x10\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x10\x00data(\x00\x00\x00\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f'
  b'']]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-dc28eae25fff> in <module>
      5         ndarray = tf.make_ndarray(value.tensor)
      6         print(ndarray)
----> 7         tf.audio.decode_wav(ndarray)
      8 

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
   7184 def raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name):
   7185   e.message += (" name: " + name if name is not None else "")
-> 7186   raise core._status_to_exception(e) from None  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   7187 
   7188 

InvalidArgumentError: contents must be scalar, got shape [4,2] [Op:DecodeWav]
```

**Edit:**

My use case is that I am writing a unittest for a custom SummaryWriter.

I have gotten a bit further, but the Tensor that I get back is not equal to the one I originally put in:

```py
paths = tf.io.gfile.glob(os.path.join(logdir, "events.out.tfevents.*"))
for path in paths:
    for event in tf.compat.v1.train.summary_iterator(path):
      for value in event.summary.value:
        ndarray = tf.make_ndarray(value.tensor)
        retrieved = np.hstack([tf.audio.decode_wav(r, desired_channels=2).audio.numpy() for r in ndarray[:, 0]]).reshape(4, 10, 2)
        print(retrieved)
        np.testing.assert_allclose(audio.numpy(), retrieved)
```

gives as output:

```py
[[[0.        0.9999695]
  [0.9999695 0.9999695]
  [0.9999695 0.9999695]
  [0.9999695 0.9999695]
  [0.9999695 0.9999695]
  [0.9999695 0.9999695]
  [0.9999695 0.9999695]
  [0.9999695 0.9999695]
  [0.9999695 0.9999695]
  [0.9999695 0.9999695]]

 [[0.9999695 0.9999695]
  [0.9999695 0.9999695]
  [0.9999695 0.9999695]
  [0.9999695 0.9999695]
  [0.9999695 0.9999695]
  [0.9999695 0.9999695]
  [0.9999695 0.9999695]
  [0.9999695 0.9999695]
  [0.9999695 0.9999695]
  [0.9999695 0.9999695]]

 [[0.9999695 0.9999695]
  [0.9999695 0.9999695]
  [0.9999695 0.9999695]
  [0.9999695 0.9999695]
  [0.9999695 0.9999695]
  [0.9999695 0.9999695]
  [0.9999695 0.9999695]
  [0.9999695 0.9999695]
  [0.9999695 0.9999695]
  [0.9999695 0.9999695]]

 [[0.9999695 0.9999695]
  [0.9999695 0.9999695]
  [0.9999695 0.9999695]
  [0.9999695 0.9999695]
  [0.9999695 0.9999695]
  [0.9999695 0.9999695]
  [0.9999695 0.9999695]
  [0.9999695 0.9999695]
  [0.9999695 0.9999695]
  [0.9999695 0.9999695]]]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-5b9f012d0c34> in <module>
      6         retrieved = np.hstack([tf.audio.decode_wav(r, desired_channels=2).audio.numpy() for r in ndarray[:, 0]]).reshape(4, 10, 2)
      7         print(retrieved)
----> 8         np.testing.assert_allclose(audio.numpy(), retrieved)
      9 
     10 

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/testing/_private/utils.py in assert_array_compare(comparison, x, y, err_msg, verbose, header, precision, equal_nan, equal_inf)
    842                                 verbose=verbose, header=header,
    843                                 names=('x', 'y'), precision=precision)
--> 844             raise AssertionError(msg)
    845     except ValueError:
    846         import traceback

AssertionError: 
Not equal to tolerance rtol=1e-07, atol=0

Mismatched elements: 79 / 80 (98.8%)
Max absolute difference: 99.00003
Max relative difference: 99.00305
 x: array([[[  0.      ,   1.265823],
        [  2.531646,   3.797468],
        [  5.063291,   6.329114],...
 y: array([[[0.      , 0.999969],
        [0.999969, 0.999969],
        [0.999969, 0.999969],...
```